# What arguments did Maxwell use to add the extra term in Ampère's original law?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, history

I have read in Griffith's *Introduction to Electrodynamics* that Maxwell's correction on Ampère's original law, $\nabla \times \mathbf{B}=\mu_{0}\mathbf{J}$, fixes the problem that arises from applying $\nabla ·$ to the equation:

$$0=\nabla \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{B})=\mu_{0}(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J})$$

The RHS is not necessarily zero, as it happens in the cases of non-steady currents. So, using the principle of conservation of charge and Gauss's law, it can be found that adding the extra term $\epsilon_0\mu_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$ overcomes the problem.

However, Griffith says that Maxwell's reasons had not to do with the principle of conservation of charge but with the concept of "ether".

Which were these reasons he followed in order to make the correction?

Comment: Griffiths doesn't elaborate on Maxwell's reasons, but in a footnote he refers to the article [*Maxwell, Displacement Current, and Symmetry*](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1969140) by A. M. Bork. Unfortunately this article is behind a paywall.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182652/2451